# Is this function surjective? $F:(0,1) \times \mathbb{Z} \ni (a,b) \rightarrow a+b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, logic

> Consider the function
> $$F:(0,1) \times \mathbb{Z} \ni (a,b) \rightarrow a+b \in \mathbb{R}$$
> Is it surjective?

At first I thought that $F$ is not surjective, because we will not get integer numbers. But, what if $0,(9)=1$?

Comment: I think you are confusing a number with its representation. If $b$ is an integer and $a\in (0,1)$ then $a+b$ cannot be an integer. So yes, the function is not surjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first thought is indeed correct. You will never get any integer in the image of the function.

In case you are thinking of something like $$0.\bar{9} = 1,$$
note that $0.\bar{9}{\color{red}\notin}(0, 1)$ and thus, you really can't get integers in the image.

---

As a formal proof, it suffices to find some real number not in the image. So, let us show that $43$ is not.
To do this, assume the contrary. Then, there exists $(a, b) \in (0, 1) \times \Bbb Z$ such that $a + b = 43$. Now, note that
$$a = 43 - b.$$
Since $b$ is an integer, so is $43 - b$; thus, we see that $a \in \Bbb Z$. However, this is a contradiction since $a \in (0, 1)$ and $(0, 1) \cap \Bbb Z = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 2):

Your first thought is correct.

If $a\in(0,1)$ and $b\in\mathbb Z$ then $a+b\in(b,b+1)$ and for every $b\in\mathbb Z$ we have $(b,b+1)\cap\mathbb Z=\varnothing$.

This proves that: $$\mathsf{im}F\cap\mathbb Z=\varnothing$$so the function is *not* surjective.

---

Be aware that:

$$0.99999\cdots=1\notin(0,1)$$